# Reload Android webview with javascript interface

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Im in proccess of creating an Android application based on webview.
The application loads html file from android assets into the webview.

I want to create a button the reload the webview I tried to do that using javascript:

```
location.reload();
```

But im getting a toast like error message that says me that this file is not exits.
I wanted to try to do it with java inside my javascript interface class
but I cant find way to access the webview object that is in the MainActivity.

I'd appreciate your help people!.

Comment: Try setting `window.location.href`from javascript.

Comment: Nothing is changed. I changed the location to file:///android_asset/index.html and I still getting this message.
But its logical if think, it dont have permission to access file on android.
So I need to do it with java.

Answer (score 0):

From your description seems more a problem connected with the way you load HTML into the WebView.
But I've found that if you call in JS `location.reload()` the WebView seems to ignore it.

I had the idea to call, from the Android Activity, webview.reload() and trigger this call from Javascript using @JavascriptInterface.

Then some other problems arised but just for reference and posterity you can check the answer with the workaround here: [Unable to reload Android WebView from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956017/unable-to-reload-android-webview-from-javascript)